# Search Multiple Columns if parameters aren't null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to search/filter on some tables with multiple parameters. But I want that if I send some parameters as 0 or null value, it won't filter on that column.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_Load]
    ,@Name          nvarchar(200)   
    ,@User_ID       int             
    SELECT           
                 [Type]
                ,[Record_ID]
                ,[First_Name]+SPACE(1)+[Last_Name] AS Full_Name
    FROM         [dbo].[Process]    
  WHERE          [Name]     =   @Name
  AND            [User_ID]  =   @User_ID
```

This is my proc. If I send `@Name` and `@User_ID`, it will filter for both; if I send `@User_ID`, it must be filter only `[User_ID]`, or same for other. If send `@Name = ''` and `@User_ID = 0` it should return unfiltered data.
How can I do that easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you can use `or` clauses

I use @Name only, in your sample you mix @Name and @Table_Name

```
WHERE   (coalesce(@Name, '') = '' or [Name] = @Name)
  AND   (coalesce(@User_ID, 0) = 0 or [User_ID] = @User_ID)
```

Comment: I'll try in the code, I mixed them when trying to shortened the codes. :)

Comment: A bit more compact variation of the above: where coalesce(nullif(@name, ''), [name]) = [name]

Comment: At least I send `0` or `''`, I couldn't work it like that altough it works AND `(0 = @Record_User_ID OR PL.[Record_User_ID] = @Record_User_ID)` like that.